# How to set method return type based on constructor options?

Tags: typescript

Developing an open source abstraction on top of [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) that implements rate limiting.

Everything works great except I’m unable to figure out how to set the return type of `post`, `get`, `patch`, `put` and `delete` methods to the `responseType` provided using constructor options (see `responseType: options?.responseType ?? "json",`).

I used overrides to set return type using the `responseType` method argument (when provided), but I don’t know how to do that for constructor options. Could really use a hand on this!

Btw, aside from an answer here, feel free to submit a PR to https://github.com/sunknudsen/http if you want to contribute to the project.

```js
type ResponseType = "buffer" | "json" | "text"
interface HTTPOptions { responseType?: ResponseType }
interface HTTPResponse<T = unknown> { body: T }

class HTTP {
  constructor(public options: HTTPOptions) {    
    this.options.responseType = options.responseType ?? "json"; // Default response type is JSON
  }  
  public get( url: string, options: HTTPOptions & { responseType: "buffer" }): Promise<HTTPResponse<Buffer>>
  public get(url: string, options: HTTPOptions & { responseType: "json" }): Promise<HTTPResponse<JSON>>
  public get(url: string, options: HTTPOptions & { responseType: "text" }): Promise<HTTPResponse<string>>
  public get(url: string, options?: HTTPOptions): Promise<HTTPResponse>
  public get(url: string, options?: HTTPOptions): Promise<HTTPResponse> {
    return null!
  }  
}


let http = new HTTP({ responseType: "text" });

http.get("", { responseType: "text" }) // string 
http.get("") // expected string, this does not work
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwFAwJ5mHASsAZ0gDsDgAVLHAXjgCIAjAVwDMXgo64AfegKwIRiXXnRigYdVAEti4qCwCGAYxwAJcuQAKAeTAxpQgojhRCJMpWwB+AFx5zRilRQy5HJargbt+Ik4AecjhaJmIAa2IIAHdiAD4TBggAEwx7YLRUZQAbRQJjHy1EVDg4ZSMYKCZlGGgACjAmBmzpZTgIfUNSe0K9AyMAShNSuBKRmAALaQIAOg7+0hmzf1JnbBD2zqMlx1WrHGtrfkFhAG44AHoLuAARYCUmbPhlixxMdem4ACkAZR0AOTGyFKY0azVacAA5sAYHU4EwoNl7ARKrJIQAaTYLAg9TS6LakOAAMhMLyc+3sjFY7E4KAG9i0UAgAFtpsAAoU-K8AgAhakcOJxUFNFptaGwhFIuAoqBozHzLo47x4vqK4mk3aWKiUgRCLjIelwRkstkcvFcwK-AGC4XgsUwuqS5Go4gYrGK3HaVVGdVIMl7bX0cQgSR0hlM1lkM2+TXsmVom2lMGiqEOp3Sl1uhVGOzKr0EgiG42R9mc2NCpMiiHix2I52y13ygu53oFosR01llZkBIIMalMwwBHEODER7ZACEQJBmVQ2RhcAmMBgYA2xGA0TzWjqftjFKDEn1A1OqFQS5XMxrdDomN33bWwEpwdDBsu13jrtG57Al4d16GVxwKA2A1MAyQZg2bqTJ8yQQIQo4QPA0TQOEqBAA)

Comment: Could you please try to boil down the example a bit? It should be just enough to demonstrate the issue. Usage example with what is expected and what doesn't work is also a good idea. I would love to help, but just figuring out all the moving parts would take too long, at least for me.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks for the feedback. I tried but perhaps with too little context. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60724250/how-to-set-generic-type-programmatically-based-on-default-or-argument-type/60724793.

Comment: Yeah, that was too little context, overloads is the answer I would have given as well to that question :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Working on a simpler proof of concept. Hope you have a chance to look at it. Will ping you via this thread once I have updated the question. :)

Comment: I simplified it. Take a look, I hope I kept the original intent, if not feel free to undo the edit.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Edit on point. Have an answer? :D

Comment: Yup, working on that now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the problem is capturing the type information in the constructor. We need to know the type of `responseType` passed when the class is created. Whenever we need to capture call site info, a generic type parameter is usually the way to go.

So we can change the class to :

```
class HTTP<TResponseDefault extends ResponseType = "json"> {
  constructor(public options: HTTPOptions & { responseType?: TResponseDefault }) {    
    this.options.responseType = options.responseType ?? "json" as TResponseDefault; // Default response type is JSON
  }
}
```

This will ensure we have the necessary info in the method, as we have captured in the type of any created `HTTP` object when `responseType` is passed in:

```
let httpJson = new HTTP({}); //  HTTP<"json">
let httpText = new HTTP({ responseType: "text"}); //  HTTP<"text">
```

Now that we have this info, we can see about making the return type dependent on it. While overloads are usually a good first approach to this, in this case since the default can come from either the the class or the call, and because there are many options and methods, I would go with another approach.

What we can do is make the method generic with a generic type parameter to capture the response type. This generic type parameter will default to the class type parameter. So if no response type is specified in the call `TResponseDefault` will be used. We can then use this type parameter to index into an interface where we map from response types to actual types:

```
interface TypeToResponseType {
  "buffer" : HTTPResponse<Buffer>
  "json" : HTTPResponse<object>
  "text" : HTTPResponse<string>
}

class HTTP<TResponseDefault extends ResponseType = "json"> {
  constructor(public options: HTTPOptions & { responseType?: TResponseDefault }) {    
    this.options.responseType = options.responseType ?? "json" as TResponseDefault; // Default response type is JSON
  }  

  public get<TResponse extends ResponseType = TResponseDefault>(url: string, options?: HTTPOptions & { responseType?: TResponse }): Promise<TypeToResponseType[TResponse]>
  public get(url: string, options?: HTTPOptions): Promise<HTTPResponse> {
    return null!
  }  
}


let httpJson = new HTTP({}); //  HTTP<"json">
let httpText = new HTTP({ responseType: "text"}); //  HTTP<"text">

let a = httpJson.get("", { responseType: "text" }) // string 
let b = httpJson.get("") // object
let c = httpText.get("") // string
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwFAwJ5mHASsAZ0gDsDgAVLHAXjgCIAjAVwDMXgo64AfegKwIRiXXnRigYdVAEti4qCwCGAYxwAJcuQAKAeTAxpQgojhRCJMpWwB+AFx5zRilRQy5HJargbt+Ik4AecjhaJmIAa2IIAHdiAD4TBggAEwx7YLRZeU8cKwoIPwtnbERUOHpmNg4uex8tQsCAIVZ2KDiy-kFhOFrNesdSYACIBj5gZRh28rEJGu8+hsGAghgoWQBzdrRUZQAbRQJjOqDFsgARYCUmXfgJYGJk41Pimk6hOgSEDuUjVaYJ6AACjATAYu2kyjgEH0hlIvW0egMRjgADITGZ-IM8nY4ORnhcrjcUABKEzlOAdcowAAW0gIADpoUjSPSMUU8iEoTCjKyBpYXNZrG9ugdcfjLoprjAANxwAD0crgBMlRLZTjgmBKdLgACkAMo6AByHWQ5Q6HRBYIhcHWwBgJz5ODuDyejo5tDxjuVUrigKYUF29hWa2I6wANFzmQQcXVEbDjGikGqsVQcZ7MWQSfYtFAIABbOlDPLkApuqgAbXTRQAulM4JbwZDbTA-QGg6sNhGmfGY3040ZidncwWyAE6s9PpTTHb-cQ4MRrrsAIQms3bVC7O1wakwGBgHVdTnEYDRebaQEIZDE2UK8rHOgCd7tTfwHd78gSI8ns9aC-TjMvPYMwgJIV43oqP4BMBkjtBuW6KJyb77l09LNoCdB0BGSZltgQHiCBXBXvKirBhsFIvnADCIbuyFCKhdroXQpK3iMYwTHB8CQrQSEfiB9EthhzEkR2oYUkAA)

Comment: This answer looks amazing. Need to eat some lunch before I’m ready to process it (never played with `extends`). Thanks Titian! :D

Comment: @sunknudsen sure no rush, if you need any help with it let me know :)

Comment: Is it normal that the type of `a` is `Promise<HTTPResponse<object>>` when `responseType` is set to `"text"`? Should be `Promise<HTTPResponse<string>>` right?

Comment: @sunknudsen small typo in `get` fixed, I left the reposneType as `"text"` instead of `TResponse `

Comment: Very promising although, admittedly, I don’t understand how this all works yet. Having a hard time implementing your answer with a second `get` option from my initial code block (`headers`). Have a moment to look at this TypeScript Playground (had to shorten the link)? https://lickst.at/9OJKra0

Comment: @sunknudsen Just make `responseType` optional in the parameter: `options?: HTTPOptions & { responseType?: TResponse }`

Comment: Thanks so much for you help Titian! I spend so much time trying to figure this one out. :)