# Conditional return type of class method depending on options in constructor

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, conditional-types

I'm sure this is possible in TypeScript, but the closest resource I could find is [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60775005/1801496) which doesn't seem to work for me.

I have a class that gets options passed in the constructor, and based on that one of its methods should change its return type from `string` to `string[]`:

```
(new MyClass({ multiple: true })).getData(); // returns string[]

(new MyClass({ multiple: false }).getData(); // returns string
```

What I've tried is to make the options generic and have a conditional return type in `getData`:

```
type Options = {
  multiple: boolean;
}

class MyClass<O extends Options> {
  constructor(private options: O) {}

  public getData = (): O["multiple"] extends true ? string[] : string => {
    if (this.options.multiple) {
      return ["foo", "bar"] as string[];
    }

    return "foo" as string;
  };
}
```

But this gives the error `TS2322: Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'O["multiple"] extends true ? string[] : string'.`.

Then I found the SO question linked above and thought that perhaps the "extraction" of `O["multiple"]` is too complex for TS, so I extracted only the "multiple" field into a generic (instead of the whole options object):

```
class Day<TReturnsArray extends boolean> {
  constructor(private options: { multiple: TReturnsArray }) {}

  public getData = (): TReturnsArray extends true ? string[] : string => {
    if (this.options.multiple) {
      return ["foo", "bar"] as string[];
    }

    return "foo" as string;
  };
}
```

But, alas, same error here. I'm not sure why `string[]` isn't assignable the conditional return type, and the error message doesn't try to "drill down" like other error messages usually do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to overload your method:

```js
type Options = {
    multiple: boolean;
}

class MyClass<O extends Options> {
    constructor(private options: O) { }
    public getData(): O["multiple"] extends true ? string[] : string
    public getData() {
        if (this.options.multiple) {
            return ["foo", "bar"];
        }

        return "foo" as string;
    };
}

const stringArray = (new MyClass({ multiple: true })).getData(); // returns string[]

const string = (new MyClass({ multiple: false })).getData(); // returns string
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/weBrVN)

COnditional type only works/sopported in overloaded signatures

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how I missed that part of the docs... It worked like a charm!

Comment: I know follow-up questions are against the rules, but it's not worth to create a new post just for it... You wouldn't know how to pass a default parameter for `options` in the constructor, while still letting TS figure out `O`? It says: "defaultOptions is assignable to the constraint of type 'O', but 'O' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Options'."

Comment: @Lesik2008 please provide small example in TS playground. Default `O` should be a subtype of Options.